# How to correctly format a Datetime value of Access using UCanAccess?

Tags: ms-access, format, ucanaccess

About format function with UCanAccess.

How is the correct way to format both months and minutes?

Because I am using it like this:

```
format(fecha_recepcion, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss")
```

And then in the minutes appears the same value of the month.
I tried different options but I always get month instead of minutes.

For example, in the database the Datetime is loaded like this:

```
23/12/2019 00:00:01
```

And then after the format function is applied UCanAccess return this:

```
2019-12-23 00:12:01
```

instead of:

```
2019-12-23 00:00:01
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try nn instead of mm for minutes.